# How to make the WPF Datagrid editable while creating dynamically, without giving any Itemsource

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

I am new to WPF, I am creating a datagrid dynamically by taking the NoOfRows & NoOfColumns as input. But the datagrid is not becoming Editable as I am not passing any Item source.

Is There any way of making the datagrid editable while not giving any Item source?

My Code is Like this (I have taken checkbox columns as datagrid column, I want to check the checkboxes):

```
var row = Convert.ToInt32(TbxLevels.Text);
var column = Convert.ToInt32(TbxPositions.Text);

Dgrid.Columns.Clear();
Dgrid.Items.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)
{
    var c = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();                   
    c.Header = column;                    
    Dgrid.Columns.Add(c);                
}


for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    Dgrid.Items.Add(i);
}
```

Comment: `DataGrid` is used in `99.9999%` to visualize underlying data and in `95%` it's done by using binding. Using it as data holder itself is not really `wpf`. And it's not editable, because it can not resolve how to edit `int` with `CheckBox` (I wonder why it works at all if it works).